# get this error from website euro-millions "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: web, reset

Since a time I get this error "This site can’t be reached" when I want to check this web site "https://www.euro-millions.com/results".

I did also test it with other browsers (edge, brave firefox) , also I removed the wifi from my iphone and used the 4G network and I get the same error.

But when I was on holiday in Belgium it was working on my iphone and labtop.
The problem is not in my computer nor Iphone.

I'm living in Spain.

I try to use wireshark but it https and I can't see the reason for rejection.

And idea what could be the cause?

thanks